# flipping div from flipping content demo not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, animation, css-transitions

I have created a Flipping div (transitions and 3d transforms) based on http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com Flipping content Demo 1.

It works great on all browsers, but IE 9 does not support transitions and 3D transforms.  I don't need the div to FLIP for IE9, but i would like the .face.front side of the image to show, instead the .face.back side appears.  I would like to write a JavaScript to say if IE9 or lower, then display .face.front

http://jsfiddle.net/RC7WH/

Answer (score 2):

I solved my own problem.  Since IE9 does not support 3D transform, it moved from the face front div to the face back side.  i wanted that faceback side to be ignored, so that i would show the facefront side.  this is the DIV:

```
<div class="perspective">
        <div id="f1_container">
            <div class="f1_card shadow">  
                <div class="front face">
                    <img src="images/rocks01.jpg" width="448px" height="276px" alt="rocks talk"/>
                </div>
                <div class="back face center">
                    <img src="images/rocks11.jpg" width="448px" height="276px" alt="rocks talk"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I created an IE condtion which i placed within the html and now the front side is visible. WHich is all I wanted.

```
    <!--[if IE 9]><html>
       <style type="text/css">
        .face.back{
           visibility:hidden;
        }
       </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

This is all I wanted. I have embedded my design in a scroll-parallax horizontal code.  Thank you Paul Irish for the HTML5 tag idea. See this in:  http://jsfiddle.net/eJnns/113/  Thank you  http://jsfiddle.net/Q7YU3/ for the perspective / parent /child that helped me use 3d Transform in Firefox 14.

Answer (score 0):

if you put the front div second then it will stay on the front in IE9

```
     <div class="front face">
          <p> front side</p>
     </div> 
     <div class="back face center">
          <p> back side</p>
     </div>
```

change it to this ...

```
     <div class="back face center">
          <p> back side</p>
     </div>
     <div class="front face">
          <p> front side</p>
     </div>
```

see sample in IE9 here   http://jsfiddle.net/eiu165/vdrXZ/1/

Comment: I have actually tried that, but Firefox gets confused and starts with the front, jumps to back quickly, then lands on the front again

Comment: If IE 9 has a css that says .face.back {display:none) then it will stay on the face front side.  I need to write a script that will say something like <!--[If lt IE 9 ]> <DO NOT link to "flipping.css" but DO link to "noflipping.css".  This way all of the other bruwsers will diplay:block, including IE 10 (when released) and IE 9 can have  it's own way.

Comment: Could someone help me correctly write the syntex script for IE 9? very appreciated.